# array using foreach loop statement in php not displaying results

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I got the following parameters as a response from SOAP client in which all the parameters have single values which is displaying properly and only the SerialEquipment parameter is an array and have many values and not able to display the result of this parameter. It just echoing as an Array.I am trying since long time but unable to display the result for SerialEquipment.

array result using var_dump:

```
   array (size=4)
  'Emission Badge' => int 4
  'Car Tax' => float 146
  'Tax Type' => string 'D' (length=1)
  'SerialEquipment' => 
    array (size=41)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'Code' => int 204093
          public 'Desc_Short' => string 'Ablagefach mittig in GepÃ¤ckraumtrennwand;ESACO_UG(122)' (length=55)
          public 'Desc_Long' => string 'Ablagefach mittig in GepÃ¤ckraumtrennwand inkl. verschiebbarem Haltenetz' (length=72)

      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public 'Code' => int 160452
          public 'Desc_Short' => string 'Airbag fÃ¼r Fahrer und Beifahrer, 2-stufi;ESACO_UG(103)' (length=55)
          public 'Desc_Long' => string 'Airbag fÃ¼r Fahrer und Beifahrer 2-stufig' (length=41)
```

Code:

```
function getVehicleValuation()
{   
    $result = $client->getVehicleValuation($params);    
    $return = array(
    'Emission Badge'    => $result->vehicle->Emission_Badge,
    'Car Tax'   => $result->vehicle->Car_Tax,
    'Tax Type'  => $result->vehicle->Tax_Type,
    'SerialEquipment' => $result->vehicle->SerialEquipment
);
return $return; 
}
```

Display result here:

```
 if($parameter['aktion'] == 'getVehicle') 
    {       
        $returned_array=getVehicleValuation();
        foreach($returned_array as $objects) 
    {
        foreach($objects as $key => $obj) 
        {       
        echo "key.: " . $key . "<br>";
        echo $obj->Code . "<br>";
        echo $obj->Desc_Short . "<br>";
        echo $obj->Desc_Long . "<br>";       
        } 
    }  
    }
```

Comment: Use foreach for iteration or array_walk:
array_walk($vehicles, function($vehicle, $key){
  echo "{$key}=>{$vehicle['Emission Badge']}";
});

Comment: i tried everything but not getting the output as i needed and getting errors.

Comment: as the answer suggest below i used foreach same way and getting this errors:Warning: Illegal string offset 'Emission Badge' in /www/1/html/webservices/schwackeNet/index.php on line 17
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0010 134564 {main}( ) ../index.php:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [php documentation regarding arrays](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and how to use them.

```
$vehicle = getVehicleValuation();
echo $vehicle['Emission Badge'] . ', ' . $vehicle['Car Tax'] . ', ' . $vehicle['Tax Type'] . ', ' . $vehicle['SerialEquipment'] . '<\ br>';
```

Comment: Believe me its not that simple..i am getting errors for every parameters now as Warning: Illegal string offset 'Emission Badge' in /www/1/html/webservices/schwackeNet/index.php and i tried foreach also before but still getting errors..i think i have to use 2 foreach loop but dont know how to use it

Comment: Ah i see, your array is not multidimensional, then is simple. You dont need to iterate over the result, i updated the code. But please you should learn some basics regarding coding.

Comment: I also added an link to the php documentation for you about arrays.

Comment: yes definately thank you very much...But still i am getting output as 4, 146, D, Array :( same like before... and without iterating how can i get the all the values from SerialEquipment Parameter ? And without iterating i also cant format my output properly i guess...

Comment: That are the values of the corresponding array keys. `SerialEquipment` seems to be also an array which you need to iterate.

Comment: You are right 2 foreach loop needed ...As u say I tried to echo other values simply and iterate for SerialEquipment and still getting error as Warning: Illegal string offset 'SerialEquipment' in /www/1/html/webservices/schwackeNet/index.php . I am very near to output but getting such errors..

Comment: My problem is that only i know how to use foreach loop but in this case some parameters dont have array and some parameters have so i dont know how to display them properly...

Comment: Try to use `var_dump` on your result to see and analyze the variable structure

Comment: yes with var_dump everythings works fine but i cant use var_dump to display my results...it will be unformatted results right...please check the result using var_dump in updated question

Comment: Now i am getting all the values for SerialEquipement but getting the error for the previous parameters...in updated question...can you please tell me where i am doing wrong ?